# I am developing a website on Nextjs and i want my Blogs page to be installed in Wordpress ? How can i do this?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, custom-wordpress-pages, nextjs-image, nextjs-storybook

I have developed a website on Nextjs and now I want my Blogs page in Wrdpress

How can I install Wordpress for my Blogs Page and do customization in wp only ???

Please help me in installing Wordpress for my existing Nextjs Website ???

Comment: You could make the blog page a subdomain - then Wordpress could be installed separately in its usual way. But I'm not an expert, and will follow this question to see if there are any other solutions

Comment: You might want to look into headless WordPress: https://vercel.com/guides/wordpress-with-vercel

Answer (score 1):

Check this Vercel Manual out about Headless Wordpress or in General **Headless CMS** if it doesnt have to be Wordpress and can be for example StrapiJS, Sanity.

Which allows you to use whatever Frontend-UI Library/Framework like Vue/Nuxt,Angualar,React/Next and handle a CMS the Backend or Content Stuff because you dont want to always rewrite JSX etc.

1. [Vercel with Headless Wordpress](https://vercel.com/guides/wordpress-with-vercel)
2. [Sanity](https://www.sanity.io/?adgroupid=138559557526&adid=676625428689&gclid=CjwKCAiA8NKtBhBtEiwAq5aX2K-X6In6X6zGeGbhYpPyNZasszK4cVhwbiN-BMPhCyTcgFz18IYiUBoCeowQAvD_BwE)
3. [StrapiJS](https://strapi.io/integrations/nextjs-cms)